# React memo with navigation drawer in react native

Tags: react-native

I am using navigation drawer in react native & on dashboard initial route i have javascript graph & when i navigate to other pages & come back i want to optional refresh it. It depends from which page user is coming from for example if user navigates to detail page & come back graph should not refresh & incase user navigates to come other screen like help screen & come back it should not refresh.

I found a way to not the refresh routes were to put `unmountInactiveroutes` in drawer options, but then all routes where not refresh which was hard to maintain.

Another option i tried using memo to remember dashboard component state but it is not working.

Any clue will be appreciated.

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home
  },
.....
  SearchResultPage :{
    screen: SearchResultPage
  }
}, {
  initialRouteName: AppConstants.NAV_HOME,
  //unmountInactiveRoutes: true,
  navigationOptions: {
    headerVisible: false
  },
  headerMode: AppConstants.NONE,
  contentComponent: props => <Sidebar {...props}/>
})

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Drawer: {
    screen: Drawer,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  }
}, {
  initialRouteName: AppConstants.NAV_DRAWER,
  //unmountInactiveRoutes: true,
  headerMode: AppConstants.NONE
})

let AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Comment: Can you post your navigation code ?
Its look like you're using 'navigation.navigate' instead of 'navigation.push'

Comment: @BloodyMonkey navigation.push not responding anything seems like if the screen is already there then we can push, any clue ?

Comment: @BloodyMonkey yes i  m using navigate, can you please help, push is not working

Comment: Weird... Maybe review your navigation, there is probably a problem.
The doc say:
'Each time you call push we add a new route to the navigation stack. When you call navigate it first tries to find an existing route with that name, and only pushes a new route if there isn't yet one on the stack.'
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating#navigate-to-a-route-multiple-times